# OpenBUGS - Variable is not defined

Tags: bayesian, openbugs

I'm using the following code in OpenBUGS to perform an analysis:

```
model
{
for(i in 1:467)
{
probit(p[i])<-gamma0+gamma1*drug[i]+gamma2*CD41[i]
R[i]~dbern(p[i])
junk[i]<-ID[i]
}
gamma0~dnorm(0,.0001)
gamma1~dnorm(0,.0001)
gamma2~dnorm(0,.0001)
}
ID[] drug[] CD41[] R[]
1   0   114 NA
2   1   40  NA
3   1   12  0
4   0   15  0
....
END
```

And I'm receiving the following error: Variable CD41[] is not defined. I'm not sure how to fix this problem, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are passing the vector variable `CD41` correctly to your dataList?

If are using R, try to call `CD41<-as.vector(CD41)` before passing it to OpenBUGS. Remember that 1 column matrix and a vector are different things for both BUG and for R.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The format I used is generally how I've passed large variable vectors to OpenBUGS in the past. I am using the OpenBUGS software and not the R package. Edit: If I can't figure it out I will try to implement it in the R package later as an alternative and see if that fixes it. I don't have time to do that right now though.

Comment: I see, but first check carefully if you haven't miss typed anything while passing your data to BUGS or anything like that, the error might be there.

Comment: So I found the error, I had an NA in my data for a dependent variable. Thanks for your help.